# Materia UI slider dissapears when I move it to the first element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

When I slide the Material UI Slider to the first element it simply dissapears as showed

[via GIPHY](https://giphy.com/gifs/TJa03M8J14LsaDJd1d)

I've been 5 hours trying to find what is the error but I am not been able.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What is happening

There was a very small mistake when specifying the min and the max from the slider.

### Solution

Be very careful when specifying the slider parameters because this doesn't provide any error messages sometimes.